# Preselect value in dropdown in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to preselect a value in a dropdown/selectbox in Angular. It should be really simple, but it will not work.

This is my markup:

```
                <select name="type" ng-model="ctrl.typeId" required>
                    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Type 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Type 4</option>
                </select>
```

In my controller i simply have:

```
vm.typeId = 2;
```

But it does not select anything. Instead, when using inspector on the dropdown element i see a new `<option>` with the value `"? number:2 ?"`.

What am i missing?

Comment: try this vm.typeId ='2';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not need to ctrl in controller

```
 $scope.typeId="2"
```

for selecting option with value 2

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.typeId ='2';
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select name="type" ng-model="typeId" required>
                    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Type 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Type 4</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select dropdown will give you a string so if you want to set something in dropdown you should initialize its model with a string value not number value.

Try this - `vm.typeId = "2";`

Comment: Ahh. Then what do i do when the value is returned as an int from another value? Convert it somehow, or?

Comment: Yes convert it to string then initialize it to dropdown model ex. xyz.toString()